# Java 1.8.0_271 non-compliant to TLS RFC: during handshake, server closes TCP connection without close_notify or alert

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, wireshark, tcpdump

We used to Weblogic 12c servers on old java versions (1.8.0_51). After upgrading to 1.8.0_271, we have an intermittent issue: after working fine for a few minutes, TLS handshakes incoming to Weblogic fail.

The observed behaviour is as follows:

```
Client --[TCP SYN]--> Weblogic
Weblogic --[TCP SYN, ACK]--> Client
Client --[TCP ACK]--> Weblogic
Client --[Client Hello]--> Weblogic
Weblogic --[TCP FIN, ACK]--> Client
```

The handshake is being made using TLS 1.3.

This seem very unusual. I read through RFC 8446 (The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.3), and I was not able to find any reason why the server would close the TCP connection without sending an alert or a close_notify first. I'd even say that, from my understanding, the JVM behaviour is non-compliant:

```
   Each party MUST send a "close_notify" alert before closing its write
   side of the connection, unless it has already sent some error alert.
```

Going back to Java 1.8.0_51 is fixing the issue.

We have this issue on both Linux and Solaris servers, and we see this issue when doing tests both remotely and locally (on the CLI of the server, using openssl s_client). So there is no way that a firewall, WAF, IPS or anything else could cause this issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like you did your research, but you forgot to ask an actual question.

Comment: with 1.8.0_51, is the handshake made by tls1.3, or tls1.2?

Comment: TLS 1.2. I found a bug ID that's actually very similar from my own issue (except for the X509TrustManager part).

Comment: The similar bug is: JDK-8198734

Comment: Your diagram shows client-->WebLogic and Server-->WebLogic, which can't both exist in a single TCP connection. WebLogic _is_ the TCP/TLS (and HTTPS) server and should respond to the client. Also, the truncation attack that close_notify is needed to block can only occur after keyexchange is successfully completed, so I think this case (assuming it's really to client) is not actually nonconforming, although it is definitely unhelpful and poor practice, and thus atypical of JSSE. Is there anything in the log(s) at the time of the problem?

Comment: Another thought occurred: are your servers running on virtual machines and if so are you looking at a real NIC/net or a virtualized one? I have seen problems similar to this with virtualization. If so, and perhaps if not, can you capture at _JVM_ level with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`? (Note this can be voluminous, and contain sensitive info.)

Comment: Oh right, my diagram as a bit messed up. I have fixed it now. I'm pretty sure the issue is not with the virtualization layer, because I have experienced it on both Linux and Solaris servers.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could try disabling `TLSv1.3` on your `Java 1.8.0_271` version.

Even if there are more consistent ways to do so, in order to test it in a fast way, you could define it **dynamically**; Place this sentence directly in your code, before the connection related methods:

```
java.lang.System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

Another option would be definning it **statically**. For example, while launching it from a terminal:

```
$ java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" YourJavaProgram
```

This will disable any protocol not included in the list, so no `TLSV1.3` will ever be accepted by your client; The server will now ask for the next protocol in its list, by default `TLSv1.2`. This is properly enabled on your side and seems to work without issues on your environment.

*I'f im not wrong, `1.8.0_271` changed some specifications regarding TLS3, such as maximum number of certs allowed, etc.* The core issue could be related to this specifications. This workaround is more a *temporal fix* than a solution, but still, hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: That is for outgoing connections (only) not incoming. Even if there were a similar property for server-side, which there isn't, and you controlled the code receiving connections, which in a framework like WebLogic you don't, JSSE sysprops are read once and cached when the relevant internal classes are _loaded_ which will generally occur early in the program execution. You can disable protocol(s) for _both_ client and server, again at load time, using _security_ properties (not sysprops). (patched)

Answer (score 0):

I have think I have finally found the cause of this issue: there is this JAR that is found in the CLASSPATH: bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar. It is from 2008, and has been built for JDK 1.4. It contains an org.bouncycastle.jce.provider class.

When we enable Weblogic's SSL debugging, we can see that it is the cause - and this is an issue that is known to happen when using outdated Bouncy Castle libraries.

Now, there's still one thing I'm not quite sure about: when we start Weblogic, it is doing fine for 5-40 minutes. It is able to process hundreds of client requests and TLS handshake. And at one point, it just stops working: all TLS handshakes that would process fine before are now receiving TCP FIN. It's almost like if the bouncycastle JCE provider overrides the default JCE provider on runtime, after a long delay. I'm not sure if that's possible.

```
####<2020-12-07 15 h 53> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <hostname.domain.com> <AdminServer> <ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <5226be2e-62b3-4804-8063-b75cf217d5f2-00000068> <1607374405613> <[severity-value: 128] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]).
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate ECDH keypair
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHKeyExchange$ECDHEPossession.<init>(ECDHKeyExchange.java:116)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHKeyExchange$ECDHEPossessionGenerator.createPossession(ECDHKeyExchange.java:230)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLKeyExchange$T12KeyAgreement.createPossession(SSLKeyExchange.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLKeyExchange.createPossessions(SSLKeyExchange.java:88)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T12ServerHelloProducer.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHello.java:432)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T12ServerHelloProducer.produce(ServerHello.java:294)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:420)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T12ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:964)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:718)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:683)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:970)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:917)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:211)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:113)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.isMessageComplete(JSSEFilterImpl.java:308)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:975)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:916)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.process(NIOSocketMuxer.java:596)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.processSockets(NIOSocketMuxer.java:560)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:43)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
Caused By: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHKeyExchange$ECDHEPossession.<init>(ECDHKeyExchange.java:111)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHKeyExchange$ECDHEPossessionGenerator.createPossession(ECDHKeyExchange.java:230)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLKeyExchange$T12KeyAgreement.createPossession(SSLKeyExchange.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLKeyExchange.createPossessions(SSLKeyExchange.java:88)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T12ServerHelloProducer.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHello.java:432)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T12ServerHelloProducer.produce(ServerHello.java:294)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:420)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T12ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:964)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:718)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:683)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:970)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:917)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:211)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:113)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.isMessageComplete(JSSEFilterImpl.java:308)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:975)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:916)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.process(NIOSocketMuxer.java:596)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.processSockets(NIOSocketMuxer.java:560)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:43)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```